# How to extract counts after comparing in 2d array in excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

[format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BPrHH.png)

hello all,

I want the answers of all users compared with the correct answer row. The total count for wrong answers should be listed in column Q for one user. How to go about it? can't get my head cracking. Image attached with name "format".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In cell Q3 and copied down:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(B3:P3<>$B$2:$P$2))
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use an array formula (should press CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER to enter the formula) to achieve this:

Q3 Formula should be:

```
{=SUM(IF($B$2:$P$2=$B3:$P3,1,0))}
```

And R3 formula should be:

```
{=SUM(IF($B$2:$P$2=$B3:$P3,0,1))}
```

Alternatively for R3, you may subtract Q3 from the total count of $B2:$P2